# Determining which of two events is nearer?

Tags: java, time

I'd like to know which event is nearer.

Now, the code that I've written relies on a comparison and it doesn't seem to work every time.

As always with everything that I try to do I'd like a solution which is both clean and efficient (feel free to criticize my code).

The events have a specific hour (ex. 16:00), a hint on how add this level of detail would be nice.

Here is the code:

```
public static int getNextEvent() 
{

    int event1 = 2; //Those events happen every week and have specific
                    //hours (didn't implement those because I have no
                    //idea how to, suggestions are greatly appreciated here)
    int event2 = 6;
    int result = 0;
    int currentDay = 6; //Days go from monday (1) to sunday (7), here this is hardcoded, in the actual program it is not.
    List<Integer> eventList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (currentDay <= event1) //This is the comparison I was talking about
    { 
        eventList.add((event2-currentDay)); // These two are in this specific order because I use the indexOf for later methods (yes, those events are hardcoded, that's fine)
        eventList.add((event1-currentDay)); //
    }
    else
    {
        currentDay = currentDay - 7;
        eventList.add((event2-currentDay)); // These two are in this
                                            // specific order because
                                            // I use the indexOf for
                                            // later methods (yes,
                                            // those events are
                                            // hardcoded, that's fine)
        eventList.add((event1-currentDay)); //
    }

    result = determineClosestEvent(eventList) + 1; // I add 1 because my other methods 
                                                   //do not start at 0 but at 1 
                                                   //(see ^ that comment)

    return result;
}

private static int determineClosestEvent(List<Integer> eventList) 
{

    int closestDay = 10;
    int listGet;

    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) 
    {
        listGet = eventList.get(i);
        if (closestDay > listGet) 
        {
            closestDay = listGet;
        } else {}
    }

    closestDay = eventList.indexOf(closestDay);

    return closestDay;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an assignment or anything, but if everything in this code is up to you, you should definitely use structures made for this purpose such as [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Comment: @ArthurAttout, I thought of that, the problem is the events are not a one time thing (I can't really hardcode the date).

Comment: What do you mean, "not a one time thing" ? There are a lot of constructors in GregorianCalendar, one of them is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Those events happen every week.

Comment: Hmmm .. So what ? When you call the constructor for Gregorian Calendar with no parameters, it constructs an object based on the current time. Using those kind of structures will spare you a lot of hair pulling, rather than re-constructing everything manually

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: If your compiler supports java 8, I suggest not using GregorianCalendar, and look at the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package which provides very useful methods for working with date and time

Comment: "*Determining which of two events is nearer?*" Nearer to what?

Comment: @smac89 To the current time.

Comment: That function take a list of times. Where do you define current time in that method?

Comment: `currentDay` actually calls a method that retrieves the current day and transforms it into an int. I hardcoded it for debugging reasons.

Comment: The event closest to the `currentDay` is the event for which `Math.abs(eventDate - currentDay)`, is the least. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. If the current day is sunday(7), this won't work. `abs[6(event2) - 7 (currentTime)]` returns 1, which means that event2 is closer than event1 (incorrect).

Comment: The nearest event is the one with the smallest difference to the current day. So you should look for a general solution to build a difference for a given event and your event. If you look for the nearest event in the future, that's another question, but similar - just filter the eventlist before. For repeated events in the future, you may add 7 to every event < currentDay to get all dates from next week. So for saturday, the next event might be on monday, not on the last thursday.

Comment: Btw.: I've seldomly seen a code with such few things happening, but so unclear what is going on. And why do you need an empty else block? What are double braces good for? The assignment to closesDay, just to return it immediately. Why not returning the indexOf directly? Why aren't you using a simplified for-loop? And a terrible comment style, unflexible and therefore hindering changes.

Comment: @userunknown well sorry for the terrible comment style. I don't comment like that, a user edited it like that. The assignment of closesDay is nice to make the code cleaner and easier to understand (also, the compiler should optimize it himself). I don't know why I am not using simplified for loops honestly. Everything else you pointed out is nice to have to make the code flow in my head better (also, it should be automatically optimized by the compiler).

Comment: @A.Pecora: No. You have int result declared in effective code line 4. Then nothing happens to it. Not in the if branch, not in the else branch. It's initialiized to 0 with no reason. You could and should have declared it at first usage (if at all, see comment before) so that we don't have to ask ourselves, why it get's overridden without condition. Small variable scope means simpler reasoning about code. In meth. 2, closestDay is initialized to 10 - as a surely too high value, as you made the comment, that days are between 1 and 7. Can't the method be called with an empty event list? NPE!

Comment: @userunknown Well you are indeed right. Thanks for pointing that out. If you have anything else to point out do it! I really enjoy criticism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167125/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-a-pecora).

Comment: @A.Pecora Edit Your Question to add further information rather than post as Comments.

Comment: @A.Pecora Well, imho you should have a method, which expects a Collection of events. Your description talks about 16:00 but then we only see a currentDay and 2 fixed events. That's not test friendly. Well, maybe you should have 2 methods, one for preprocessing the events, one for the final judgement, but the setup for the list shouldn't be in either of those.

Comment: @ArthurAttout The troublesome `GregorianCalendar` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Design an `Event` class for your events. Use `DayOfWeek` (from java.time, the modern Java date and time API) for the event’s day of week and `LocalTime` for the time of day.

To find out how far into the past or future each event is, first use `ZonedDateTime.now(yourTimeZone)` to determine the current date and time. Given that `currentDateTime` is a `ZonedDateTime`, use `currentDateTime.toLocalDate().getDayOfWeek()` to get today’s day of week.

For each event, if it doesn’t happen today, consider both the previous occurrence and the next one (if this is appropriate according to your requirements). Use `TemporalAdjusters.previous()` and `TemporalAdjusters.next()` to find the dates. Then `LocalDate.atTime` and `LocalDateTime.atZone` to get a `ZonedDateTime` for when the event happened or happens. Now that you have a `ZonedDateTime` for current time and one for the event time, use `Duration.between()` to find how far into the past or the future this event is. You may want `Duration.abs()` to make sure the duration is non-negative. And `Duration.compareTo` for determining which duration is shorter. There you have the nearest event.

**Links**

- [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time
- [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-frame.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without taking much care about public/private issues:

```
import java.util.*;
```

/*
You can test the code by copying it into one big file, named EventTest. You might indent the comments, or delete them. I unindent them here, for better readability. Have a look at the Interface Comparable, a very useful interface, because if you define such a method, you can sort a Collection of such things with the Java methods. 
*/

```
class MyDate implements Comparable <MyDate> {
```

/* 
  Just a simple int for the day of week, like in your attempt.
*/
        int dow;

```
    public MyDate (int dow)
    {
        this.dow = dow;
    }

    // if other date is over, next date is in next week - add 7.
    public int compareTo (MyDate other) {
        int diff = other.dow - dow;
        if (diff < 0) diff += 7;
        return diff;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return "" + dow;
    }
}
```

/*
  An event has a date - let's have a name too:
*/

```
class Event {
    String name;
    public MyDate dow;

    public Event (String name, MyDate dow)
    {
        this.dow = dow;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

/*
For later usage, we supply a dateDiff method, which delegates the comparison of the date to the dow.compareTo method:
*/

```
    public int dateDiff (MyDate cmp) {
        return dow.compareTo (cmp);
    }

    public String toString () {
        return name + " " + dow;
    }
}
```

/*
  We need an extra Comparator, to compare different Events to an external given MyDate. 
*/

```
class EventComparator implements Comparator <Event>
{
    MyDate crucialDate;
    public EventComparator (MyDate crucial)
    {
        crucialDate = crucial;
    }
    public int compare (Event e1, Event e2)
    {
        int diff = (e1.dateDiff (crucialDate)) - (e2.dateDiff (crucialDate));
        return diff;
    }
}
```

/*
Now a fat testing class.
*/

```
public class EventTest {
```

/*
First try to understand, how the test2 method works, before testing the testMany () method.
*/

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test2 ();
        // testMany ();
    }
```

/*
Here the Comparator has its big moment. Well - it sorts for a given MyDate 'current' the list of events. If the list isn't empty, the first element is (one of) the closest. 
*/

```
    static List<Event> findClosest (MyDate current, List<Event> events) {
        EventComparator ec = new EventComparator (current);
        events.sort (ec);
        return events;
    }
```

/*
As in your example, 2 dates (2, 6) and a currentDay (6).
The List of Events is resorted in place and contains the same elements, probably in a different order:
*/
        static void test2 () {
            List eventList = new ArrayList<> ();
            eventList.add (new Event ("Dow: 2", new MyDate (2)));
            eventList.add (new Event ("Dow: 6", new MyDate (6)));
            MyDate currentDay = new MyDate (6);
            System.out.println ("unsorted");
            show (eventList);
            System.out.println ("sorted");
            findClosest (currentDay, eventList);
            show (eventList);
        }

```
    static void testMany () {
        Random r = new Random ();
        // eventList.add (new Event ("Dow: " + day, new MyDate (day)));
        List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            int day = r.nextInt (7) + 1;
            eventList.add (new Event ("Dow: " + day, new MyDate (day)));
        }
        for (int today = 1; today <= 7; ++today) {
            MyDate currentDay = new MyDate (today);
            System.out.println ("unsorted " + currentDay);
            show (eventList);
            findClosest (currentDay, eventList);
            System.out.println ("sorted "+ currentDay);
            show (eventList);
        }
    }

    public static void show (List <Event> events) {
        for (Event e : events)
            System.out.println (e);
    }
}
```

You may later extend the MyDate class to include hours. Semantically, I didn't check, whether the algorithm works as expected. You should write some test cases first

- 2 dates lower than today
- first lower, second higher
- first higher, second lower
- both higher than today
- different distances, same distance,
- same date as currentDay

Make a small table and first write the expected result down, then look whether it works.